# Supabase select fields from storage file list

Tags: javascript, typescript, supabase

The premise is simple. As suggested in the supabase docs I am listing all existing files in my storage bucket using :

```
    const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .list('folder', {
    limit: 100,
    offset: 0,
    sortBy: { column: 'name', order: 'asc' },
  })
```

**Is it possible to select only a certain number of fields that this query would return ?**

For example, if this were with a database I could specify the fields I want within the .select() clause. (e.g. `.select('field_1', 'field_2')`). How do I achieve this with supabase storage ? In the scenario where I want only to return the name of the files and their creation date for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the storage API doesn't support limiting which fields to be retrieved. The piece of information you retrieve with the `list()` methods are fairly small, so generally shouldn't be too much of an over head to query those extra fields though.